# Why are account inputs ordered different in similar transactions

Tags: transactions

Why are account inputs for similar transactions with similar instructions placed at a different position? For instance, in the below example, the program account is either at position 4 or 5. The transactions are built by the same frontend logic using Solana web3.js.

What determines this position? The only delta in the transaction is two addresses.

For analyzing the accounts I now need to derive the account input from an inner instruction, but would prefer to do that directly from the transaction.

**TX1:**
[image: TX_1]

**TX2 accounts #4 and #5 are swapped:**
[image: TX_2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

web3.js sorts the accounts based on what Solana expects, i.e. signers before non-signers, writables before read-onlys.

In your case, both accounts #4 and #5 are read-only non-signer accounts so it then uses their public key for sorting. In both of your screenshots, the two accounts are sorted alphabetically.

[This](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/c502fc72f6743e0fe8ab7c882d94f58a26527fe4/web3.js/src/transaction.ts#L416-L445) is the relevant part of the web3.js code where this sorting occurs.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: based on the source code it is deterministic how the "equal" accounts are sorted: it's by public key. `return x.pubkey.toBase58().localeCompare(y.pubkey.toBase58());`.

You can see in the question examples exactly what's going on from there: `AAtZ...` comes before `DCDX...`, but `Test...` comes after `DCDX...`

Comment: That's not a nitpick, that's a huge fkup on my part! The whole unstable sorting algorithm doesn't even come into it. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing it out. Off to optometrist.

Answer (score 2):

The runtime only cares about the ordering of pubkeys with respect to their class as defined in [`MessageHeader`](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/message/struct.MessageHeader.html).  That is, one of: writable signers, read-only signers, writable non-signers and read-only non-signers.  Within these classes, the ordering is irrelevant, so left open for SDKs to implement as they please